# Link to section on page without using #

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a novice at the moment & learning a few things along the way but I am stuck with this small issue.
Here is the page in question http://www.theremotedoctor.co.uk/accvolvo.html
I am looking to click on my item selection as shown on the page and scroll to the page of which is the loaded upon a click.
Desktop works fine so this is for IOS device where picture loaded is off the screen,hence the scroll of the item.

I have supplied a before & after code to show what happened.

BEFORE CODE WITH WORKING PICTURE LOADED

```
<li><a href="javascript:" onclick="replaceMainImage('m-images/photos/VOLVO002.jpg', 'Volvo002','<b>£70.00</b><br>TEXT LINE 1<br>TEXT LINE 2<br>TEXT LINE 3<br><b>Uk Recorded £2.50</b><br><b>International Signed For £10.00</b><br><scan class=drColor>The Remote Doctor</scan>')">Remote uncut key</a></li>
```

AFTER CODE PICTURE LOADING NOT HAPPENING BUT SCROLL IS WORKING

```
<li><a href="#iosscroll">Remote uncut key</a><a href="javascript:" onclick="replaceMainImage('m-images/photos/VOLVO002.jpg', 'Volvo002','<b>£70.00</b><br>TEXT LINE 1<br>TEXT LINE 2<br>TEXT LINE 3<br><b>Uk Recorded £2.50</b><br><b>International Signed For £10.00</b><br><scan class=drColor>The Remote Doctor</scan>')">Remote uncut key</a></li>
```

I am now not sure how to rectify this.
If the above code of which I have applied is incorrect I am willing to use a different code that will allow the link to be clicked,pictured loaded & also the scroll to the picture working.
I understand its down to the # being used so already but now confused.

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: I see you are using jQuery elsewhere on the page - so why choose for the inline script here?

Comment: I have now sorted this issue since putting up the post,thanks.

Comment: @user3169014 you can post your answer and accept it